# Establish an upper bound for $\zeta'(s)\over\zeta(s)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, complex-integration, upper-lower-bounds, chebyshev-function

Using Perron's formula, I am able to show that

$$
\psi(x)={1\over2\pi i}\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty}\left[-{\zeta'(s)\over\zeta(s)}\right]{x^s\over s}\mathrm ds
$$

where $\psi(x)$ is the Chebyshev's psi function. Now, I aim to find an explicit formula for $\psi(x)$ by evaluating it using this contour:

[image: contour]

Writing it mathematically, we have

$$
{1\over2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma+\Gamma}\left[-{\zeta'(s)\over\zeta(s)}\right]{x^s\over s}\mathrm ds={1\over2\pi i}\int_\Gamma\left[-{\zeta'(s)\over\zeta(s)}\right]{x^s\over s}\mathrm ds+{1\over2\pi i}\int_{a-iT}^{a+iT}\left[-{\zeta'(s)\over\zeta(s)}\right]{x^s\over s}\mathrm ds
$$

where the left hand side, using argument principle, is

$$
{1\over2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma+\Gamma}\left[-{\zeta'(s)\over\zeta(s)}\right]{x^s\over s}\mathrm ds=x-{\zeta'(0)\over\zeta(0)}-\sum_{\Re(\rho)>0\atop\zeta(\rho)=0}{x^\rho\over\rho}-\frac12\ln(1-x^{-2})
$$

which conforms to the actual explicit formula for $\psi(x)$, indicating that

$$
\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_\Gamma\left[-{\zeta'(z)\over\zeta(z)}\right]{x^z\over z}\mathrm dz=0
$$

Plugging the parametrization for the $\Gamma$ contour gives

$$
\Gamma: z=a+Te^{it},\mathrm dz=iTe^{it}\mathrm dt,t:\pi/2\to3\pi/2 \\ \begin{aligned} \lim_{T\to\infty}\left|\int_\Gamma{\zeta'(z)\over\zeta(z)}{x^z\over z}\mathrm dz\right| &=\lim_{T\to\infty}\left|\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}{\zeta'(a+Te^{it})\over\zeta(a+Te^{it})}{x^{a+Te^{iT}}\over a+Te^{it}}Te^{it}\mathrm dt\right| \\ &\le\lim_{T\to\infty}x^aT\left|\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\left|\zeta'(a+Te^{it})\over\zeta(a+Te^{it})\right|{x^{T\cos t}\over|a-T|}\mathrm dt\right| \\ &=\pi x^a\lim_{T\to\infty}{T\over T-a}\color{blue}{\left|\zeta'(a+Te^{i\eta})\over\zeta(a+Te^{i\eta})\right|}{x^{T\cos\eta}} \end{aligned}
$$

Since $\eta$ is chosen between $\frac\pi2$ and $\frac{3\pi}2$, $e^{T\cos\eta}\to0$, but in order to prove that the entire integral goes to zero as $T\to\infty$, I have to establish an upper bound for the blue term. Could anybody give me a hand on this?

Comment: Yes, that integral indeed tends to $0$. It is well-known that $$\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s) = O(\log^7 t) $$ when $s = \sigma+it$, $\sigma \geq 1, t>1$. Functional equation of $\zeta$ then says $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s) = O(\log^7 |t|)$ for all $s\in \Gamma$ with $|t|>1$, $\sigma <0$.

Comment: @pisco Is there a proof for that?

Comment: An introductory reference would be *The theory of the Riemann zeta-function (2nd Edition)* by Titchmarsh, chapter $3$ section $6$. The key is the identity $3+4\cos x + \cos 2x = 2(1+\cos x)^2$. The book is also excellent if you are interested in Riemann zeta.

Comment: @pisco Thanks for that, and you are correct: it is Riemann zeta function that motivates me to learn all these mathematics!

Comment: @pisco I read your source, but I really did not find inequalities for $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$ for $\Re(s)<1$

Comment: Using function equation, you get $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s) = O(\log^A t)$ for some $A>0$ when $\Re(s) = \sigma \geq 1$ or $\sigma \leq 0$. For $s$ in critical strip, it's known that $\zeta^{(n)}(s)  = O(\log^{1/4} t)$ for any $n$ on $0<\sigma<1$.

Comment: However, you said you "proved" $$\psi(x)={1\over2\pi i}\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty}\left[-{\zeta'(s)\over\zeta(s)}\right]{x^s\over s}\mathrm ds$$ this seems nontrivial because of convergence issue. What is definitely true is the smoothened version $$\psi_1(x) = \int_0^x \psi(t) dt = {1\over2\pi i}\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty}\left[-{\zeta'(s)\over\zeta(s)}\right]{x^s\over s(s+1)}\mathrm ds$$ Then you can show, using bounds of $\zeta$ or $\zeta'$, the integral along $\Gamma \to 0$.

Comment: @pisco I would say that traversing the critical strip is tricky (need to pass between two zeros that are not too close) and we need to refer to Titchmarsh calculations, for $\Re(s) < -1$ the functional equation gives two terms $x^s\zeta'/s\zeta(1-s)$ and $x^s\chi'/s\chi(s)$, for $x > 1$ they have exponential decay in $|\Re(s)|$ thus no trouble (just make sure to pass through an odd negative integer to avoid the poles of $\Gamma'/\Gamma(s/2)$).

Comment: @reuns   Yes, making the path penetrates through the critical strip is tricky. Nonetheless I think this can be achieved via $\Omega$-results (due to Titchmarsh), which says $\zeta$ cannot be always small on critical strip, but I agree a rigorous proof would have many details to sort out.

Comment: @reuns Yeah, I do need to restrain $T$ from touching the trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$, assuming the contour does not intersect the non-trivial ones.

Comment: @pisco It appears that this thing is getting more and more complicated, and possibly using Hadamard's factorization theorem (which I was trying to prove) is easier.